# c# object pattern matching for multiple values

Tags: c#

I know this is possible:
`if (item is { InventoryItemId: 21 })`

But I need to do something like this
 `if (item is { InventoryItemId: [21, 3] })`

Is it somehow possible? I dont know how is this called, nor cannot find it after like and hour of googling. I will be glad for any input. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the condition to be true if item.InventoryItemId is 21 or 3?

Comment: @SomeBody I want to be true if it equals to any of it. Seems like this is the way... `item is { MoveGateId: 21 } or { MoveGateId: 3 }` I would like to use it like array, or collection. Is that possible?

Comment: @TomášFilip: No, a constant value is expected, thats also the compiler error that you get if you try it

Comment: I'm thinking in an aproach via Linq .Any?

Comment: Hi overload of is operator is not posible, and the linq has already excelent method for that purpous - InventoryItems.Any(x => x == item). If you need that the item is assigned after the check you can wrap the Any in method with out parameter or something like that

Comment: @TomášFilip, for a predefined set of values you can do `if (item.InventoryItemId is (21 or 3)) {}`

Comment: @ASh: Didn't know you can also do that, edited my answer

Comment: I like the solution @ASh, closest to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not supported since the value must be a constant since the pattern is evaluated at compile time. So something like this is NOT supported:

```
int[] values = { 21, 3 };
if(values.Any(v => item is { InventoryItemId: v }))
{
}
```

So either use something like this (as Ash has commented):

```
if (item.InventoryItemId is 21 or 3) 
{
}
```

or use another approach to evaluate it (what i would do):

```
if(values.Contains(item.InventoryItemId)
{
}
```